# spark : map reduce by distinct value

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I m a beginner in Scala Spark and I have a problem.

I have a map like this (with millions of lines) :

`Map("date_create1" -> "user_id1", "date_create1" -> "user_id2", "date_create1" -> "user_id1", "date_create2" -> "user_id1")`

I would like to count how many distinct users I have for each date.

Like this:

`Map("date_create1" -> 2, "date_create2" -> 1 )`

How can I do that in Scala/Spark.
If I use aggregateByKey, I can t have a distinct isn't it?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Same key can't have two different values in a Map.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you have a tuple like below. And what you need is to get distinct user by date. You could easily do this by having distinct and countByKey

```
val data = Array(("date1","user1"),("date1","user1"),("date1","user3"),("date1","user2"),("date2","user1"),("date2","user2"),("date2","user2"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
val distincCount = rdd.distinct.countByKey()
```

Output:

```
distincCount: scala.collection.Map[String,Long] = Map(date2 -> 2, date1 -> 3)
```

Comment: thanks knight71. i did that. it works but it s slow during my distinct operation :(  do you have an other solution, for example in combining distinct and countbykey and reduce the shuffle in spark ? :)